# Bash script executes too long. No output until abort

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have this script which I call with one argument. The argument is an IP address. I'm wondering about the execution time of this script. Sometimes it takes just several seconds, sometimes up to 30 minutes to see the output of the script. I have no idea why.

If I call the script, wait some seconds and abort the script with ctrl + c, I can see the output of the script immediatly. If I just wait I see the same output but 30 minutes later.

Do you have an idea why this script or my server is buggy?

Thx.

```
#!/bin/bash
#########################################
# blocks IP address permanently via ufw #
#########################################

# check if user is root
if [[ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Run as root. Exit."
  exit
fi

# check argument it given
ip=${1:?No IP address given. Exit.}

# IPv4 regex
regex4='^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\/[0-9]{2}){0,1}$'

# IPv6 regex
regex6='^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(\/[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$'

isIP=false

if [[ $ip =~ $regex4 ]]; then
  ufw insert 1 deny from $ip
  echo "$ip blocked permanently!"
  isIP=true
elif [[ $ip =~ $regex6 ]]; then
  ufw prepend deny from $ip
  isIP=true
else
  echo "IP address is wrong."
fi

#ufw status verbose

# add blocked ip to file and commit it.
if [ "$isIP" = true ] && [[ $(grep -L "$ip" ips/custom.txt) ]] ; then
  echo $ip >> ips/custom.txt
  git add ips/custom.txt
  git commit -m "added ip to ips/custom.txt"
  git push
fi
```

Comment: add a `set -x` at the top, which will show you which line is stalling. once you've done that you can also add debug-onlky comments with just a colon, like `: starting ufw insert deny $ip`, and they will print to stderr, but when you comment the `set -x` they will all be silenced.

Comment: Thank you. I added `set -x` and I can see ufw takes so long.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my script. I think the problem is the line
`echo $ip >> ips/custom.txt`
try the following:

`echo $ip >> ips/custom.txt 2>&1 &`

Let me know...

Comment: Thanks, but there is no difference.

Comment: Why would you run an echo statement in background? And I doubt you'd want the few error messages likely on an echo to go into that file instead of notifying the user...